# When to correctly use @property/@synthesize, (id)sender and release

Tags: xcode, object

I have been watching Xcode tutorials on youtube and learning from examples online but could not find a consistency in usage.

I know from  articles on this site that any object created with Alloc/Init, Copy or New must be released.

But:
- Do all objects have to use @property/@synthesize? Regardless of whether they are IBOutlets or not?
- Does (id)sender have to be used with all methods (IBAction) and (void) in .h and .m files?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties are just setters and getters for `ivars`.

```
@interface MyVC : NSObject {
    UIButton *myPropertyButton;
    UIButton *myIvarbutton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *myPropertyButton;
// No @property for myIvarbutton

@end


@implementation MyVC

@synthesize myPropertyButton;
// no @synthesize for myIvarbutton

- (void)someMethod {
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.myPropertyButton description]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [myIvarButton description]);
}

@end
```

`@synthesize` creates methods *similar* to this:

```
- (UIButton *)myPropertyButton {
    return [[myPropertyButton copy] autorelease];
}

- (void)setMyPropertyButton:(UIButton *)value {
    [value retain];
    [myPropertyButton release];
    myPropertyButton = value;
}
```

`properties` *can be* accessed via `self.someProperty` or `classInstance.someProperty` (which would call the setter/getter of `self` or `classInstance`).

---

`IBAction` and `IBOutlet` are xcode specific directives that allows you to make a connection to a method/property/ivar from an object in the Interface Builder.

---

You do not have to include `:(id)sender` in your action handlers, but you would want to if you had multiple buttons connected to the same method.  Then you can distinguish which button was clicked that called the method:

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender {
    if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) return;
    if ((UIButton *)sender == myButtonOne) {
        // do stuff
    } else if ((UIButton *)sender == myButtonTwo) {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

You should be aware, that Apple reserves all variable names starting with a leading underscore for itself.

Answer (score 0):

@property/@synthesize are used when you want to use an object as a property (as opposed to an instance variable). This means that the property will have dynamically created setters & getters, and has no bearing on memory management.

(id)sender is a method that takes a generic argument (in most cases the button "sending" the message), and can be made to be more specific if the case allows. For example, there's no reason why an IBAction-method for a UIButton can't be `-(IBAction)myMethod:(UIButton *)button;`, however if anything other than a UIButton calls that method, it'll cause problems. And no, you can certainly have `void` methods that take any number of arguments (including none).

And, as always, a good rule of thumb for non-ARC projects is:

> Call `release` once for every time you call `alloc` or `retain` on an object.